# How to get system volume level(audio) in windows?

Tags: windows, audio, powershell, nircmd

Using **[nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)** we can set system volume level(audio) but **how to get system volume**?

How can we get system volume using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to get system volume?

You can also use NirCmd for for this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SoundVolumeView.exe /GetPercent Speaker/HP
set /a _volume=%errorlevel% / 10
echo %_volume%%%
endlocal
```

where `Speaker/HP` is the name of my audio device.

---

> **Get sound level information from command line**
>
> Use the get commands of `SoundVolumeView` - `/GetPercent`, `/GetPercentChannel`, `/GetDecibel`, `/GetDecibelChannel`, `/GetMute` :
>
> These
> commands return the desired sound level information inside the Exit
> Status of the program. Because the Exit Status is an integer value,
> the percent value is multiplied by 10 and the Decibel value is
> multiplied by 1000. You can get more information about these commands
> in the 'Command-Line Options' section.
>
> You can get the desired value inside a batch file by using the `%errorlevel%` variable, for example.
>
> ```
> SoundVolumeView.exe /GetPercent Speakers
> echo %errorlevel%
> ```
>
> Be aware that the above example only works when saving the commands into a batch file and then running the batch file. If you try
> to execute it without a batch file, you'll only get zero result. It's
> not a bug in `SoundVolumeView`, it's just the way that the `%errorlevel%`
> variable works.

Source: [View / change sound volume on Windows from command line or GUI](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html#command_line)